# How to re-run cypress test case failures through Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I am running my cypress through Jenkins and Bamboo. Recently, I got so many failure based on issues out RDMS. I had to re run all the failures based on the tests spec name through Jenkins.

Is there any way to re-run my failed specs / tests through Jenkins for my Cypress automation framework ?

Answer (score 2):

Please watch Gleb Bahmutov [Cypress v12.5.0 Debug Tab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drlt4lOC0O4), at 1:18 "Run failures" button.

This Debug Tab is new to Cypress 12.5.0.

The changelog states

> **12.5.0**
> Released 01/31/2023
>
> **Features:**
>
> Easily debug failed CI test runs recorded to the Cypress Cloud from your local Cypress app with the new Debug page.

The documentation is here [Debug](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/cypress-app#Debug)

[image]